# Angular 4 codemirror performance issue (detaching zone)

Tags: javascript, angular, codemirror, zone.js

I've run into big performance problem when I tried to implement codemirror, firstly I used [ng2-codemirror](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-codemirror) but it's killed my application which has only list of scripts and codemirror component. I found out that creating `instance` (by instance i mean `CodeMirror.fromTextArea(...)`) should be run outside angular so I copied component from `ng2-codemirror` (code attached below) to my project and wrap init method with `NgZone.runOutsideAngular`, it helps but just a bit. So I've started profiling my angular project with `Javascript profiler in chrome debugger` and vanilla js codemirror with the same `code` to edit. My small research shows me that without `zone.js` codemirror is executing same function with about 8% of my CPU resources however with `zone.js` in angular project it takes 48%. So I've started to completly detach zone from `codemirror component`, So I tried with `ChangeDetectionRef.detach()` but the zone still is attached to `codemirror` (checked with JS profiler again).

Summary:
`runOutsideAngular` does not help to detach codemirror source code from zone, same is for `detaching` changeDetector for codemirror component

Code for my modified codemirror component

```
export class MpCodemirrorComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() config;
  @Output() change = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() focus = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() blur = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() cursorActivity = new EventEmitter();

  @ViewChild('host') host;

  @Output() instance = null;

  _value = '';

  private changeSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor( 
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    this.changeDetector.detach();
  }

  get value() { return this._value; }

  @Input() set value(v) {
    if (v !== this._value) {
      this._value = v;
      this.onChange(v);
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.changeDetector.detach();

    this.config = this.config || {};
    this.codemirrorInit(this.config);
    this.changeSubject
      .debounceTime(500)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe(change => this.updateValue(change));
  }

  codemirrorInit(config) {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.instance = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this.host.nativeElement, config);
      this.instance.setValue(this._value);
      this.instance.on('change', () => {
        this.changeSubject.next(this.instance.getValue());
        // this.updateValue(this.instance.getValue());
      });

      this.instance.on('focus', (instance, event) => {
        this.focus.emit({instance, event});
      });

      this.instance.on('cursorActivity', (instance) => {
        this.cursorActivity.emit({instance});
      });

      this.instance.on('blur', (instance, event) => {
        this.blur.emit({instance, event});
      });
    })

  }

  updateValue(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.onTouched();
    this.change.emit(value);
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    this._value = value || '';
    if (this.instance) {
      this.instance.setValue(this._value);
    }
  }
  onChange(_) {}
  onTouched() {}
  registerOnChange(fn) { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn) { this.onTouched = fn; }
}
```

I've run out of ideas how to completly detach zone for 3rd party library, any help is appreciated.

P.S. Don't mind doubled `changeDetector.detach()`.